# Having pytest tests share an external resource

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest to test an external object (say, a server running on a docker container). I have a couple of test modules defined - say, `tests/a_tests/tests_a.py` and `tests/b_tests/tests_b.py`.

In both `tests/a_tests/conftest.py` and `tests/b_tests/conftest.py`, the docker container is set up by a fixture like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def docker_container():
    docker container = get_docker_container()
    yield docker_container
    shut_down_docker_container(docker_container)
```

The docker container has a single IP address/set of ports defined for it, so calling `get_docker_container()` when a docker container is already running creates an error. When I run the tests currently, pytest (I'm not quite sure why) will attempt to overlap the lifetime of both `a_tests`'s `docker_container` and `b_tests`'s `docker_container`, meaning that I get an error.

What I would like is some way to avoid this scenario, by, say:

1. Having an additional fixture which somehow marks that an external resource (the docker container in this example) is in use, and prevents tests from running until it is, or
2. Fixing the order of the test modules, so I can be sure that `tests_a.py` always runs before `tests_b.py`.

The first of these two solutions seems more elegant but I can't readily see how it might be done. I've looked at the `pytest-order` library to try to implement the second, but so far as I can see it only deals with the ordering of individual tests, rather than modules.

I'm using a docker container here as a proxy for any external resource, and there are a lot of tests here that have a pretty high turnover, so it's not easily feasible to go through and use, say, `@pytest.mark.order(1)` etc. for all of them. It's also important to clear the state of the external resource between test modules, so creating a single `docker_container` fixture with session-scope does not work.

If anyone has any solutions I'd be very glad to hear them!

Comment: Have you tried `@pytest.fixture(scope="session")` (if sharing the container for the duration of the test session is okay)?

Comment: Also, you will need to have a single module declaring the fixture, e.g. `tests/conftest.py`.

Comment: @AKX thanks, I have, yes, unfortunately I need to clear the state of the external resource between test modules so this wouldn't work.

Comment: _pytest (I'm not quite sure why) will attempt to overlap the lifetime of both a_tests's docker_container and b_tests's docker_container_ - the issue is rather in your `get_docker_container()` function that returns before the container is actually spin up. Please share a [mcve] that includes the implementations of both `get_docker_container` and `shut_down_docker_container` functions.

Comment: @hoefling this question is not specifically about docker, and is general to other external resources, but the `get_docker_container` function blocks until the container has been launched. I have also attempted the same thing with breakpoints to check that the issue was not about external delays, as I think you're suggesting. I could not see any guarantees stated in the pytest documentation about the order in which tests will be executed. If you think that pytest attempting to overlap these module-scoped fixtures sounds unusual, please say so as that is a useful lead.